# How to store a rectangular array in an array list in a correct way in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, file-io, jagged-arrays

I wrote the following code to generate a population of 6 chromosomes in which each chromosome is an array of 5x5. Then I print each chromosome using another method. The problem is that I got the same array each time!!.

```
    static List<int[,]> PopulationChromosomes = new List<int[,]>();

    private void moveGenetic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:/temp/intialPopulation.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

        writer = new StreamWriter("C:/temp/listOfChromosomesForAllRounds.txt", true);

        population = new int[6][,]; // jagged array    
        Random rnd = new Random(); // to gereate random number (either 0 or 1)
        auvChromosomes = new int[5, 5];

        for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
        {
            population[i] = new int[5, 5];   
        }

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))   
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                    {
                        auvChromosomes[j, k] = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                        sw.Write("|" + auvChromosomes[j, k] + "|");
                    } // end-inner-for
                    sw.WriteLine();

                } // end-outer-inner-for
                PopulationChromosomes.Add(auvChromosomes);
                Array.Clear(auvChromosomes, 0, auvChromosomes.Length);
            } // end-outer-for

        } // end-using    

        Chromosomes(PopulationChromosomes, 1);
    }
```

Comment: So is the print wrong or the calculation? Can you provide the right results?

Comment: it is provided just follow the links to see

Comment: Please define "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are treating an int[,] as a value type, while in fact it is a reference type. When you add it to your list

```
PopulationChromosomes.Add(auvChromosomes);
```

and then clear it

```
Array.Clear(auvChromosomes, 0, auvChromosomes.Length);
```

you are clearing the instance which you just put in the list. So the array in the list will be full of zeroes.

Even without the clear, you would keep adding the same instance of the array over and over. You need to create a new array for every iteration.

Solution:

**Create a new array instance** within your for cycle and **skip the Array.Clear part**, you shouldn't need it if you create a new instance

```
 for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
 {
     auvChromosomes = new int[5, 5];
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michal S's answer already addresses the main issue, but I also wanted to help you clean up your code.

```
static List<int[,]> PopulationChromosomes = new List<int[,]>();

#region AUV Genetic Movement

private Random rnd = new Random(); // to generate random number (either 0 or 1)
private void moveGenetic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/intialPopulation.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))   
    {   
        var population = new int[6][,]; // define this in the scope where you use it
        for (int i = 0; i < population.Length; i++)
        {
            population[i] = new int[5, 5];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    population[i][j, k] = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                    sw.Write("|{0}|", population[i][j, k]);
                } // end-inner-for
                sw.WriteLine();
            } // end-outer-inner-for
            PopulationChromosomes.Add(population[i]);
        } // end-outer-for
    } // end-using    

    Chromosomes(PopulationChromosomes, 1);
}
```

and

```
private const string lineSeparator = new string('-', 90);
public void Chromosomes(IEnumerable<int[,]> population, int round)
{  
    ////////////////  print  each chromosome matrix ////////////////
    using (writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/listOfChromosomesForAllRounds.txt", true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("{0}\n********************************* List of Chrmomsomes (Round : {1})**********************************\n{2}", lineSeparator, round, lineSeparator);

        foreach (int[,] chromosme in population)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < chromosme.GetLength(0); h++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < chromosme.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    writer.Write("|{0}|", chromosme[h, k]);
                }
                writer.WriteLine();
            }
            writer.WriteLine(lineSeparator);
        }
    }
}
```

Going deeper, you really should have a `Chromesome` class to encapsulate the 2-d array.